# Industry Standard for Single-Board Computers?

Tags: hardware

Do Arduinos, or any other single-board computer, come in any sort of industry-standard form factor? I'm trying to sell management on using Arduino, but they are stuck on the question "what if Arduino goes out of business", and if I could answer "we can just switch over to using brand X because it's the same size and has the same connectors", my life would be much easier.

Comment: Arduinos are not single board computers.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - untrue, an Arduino is very much an SBC

Comment: I'm going to agree with @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams -- the Arduino is just a microcontroller with a few extra peripherals attached around it to make it easier to develop with. Single board computer is generally a term for a board that has a Microprocessor (i.e. not microcontroller), some RAM, and optionally storage and maybe a GPU built in to the CPU. SBC would more like a Raspberry Pi or BeagleBone Black.

Comment: There are standards if you're willing to look beyond Arduino, such as [PC/104](http://pc104.org/), but for Arduino (hardware) you're pretty much stuck with whoever is making boards for them. You may want to consider standardizing your own I/O and Arduino libraries, and seeing how they work with the various Arduino-compatible MCUs.

Comment: @JakeC - no.  An Arduino has all of the same types of resources as most other SBCs - granted it is less powerful, but not less powerful than some of the first systems to define that term.  That a microcontrontroller puts peripherals such as volatile and non-volatile storage that might have once had to be a on the board on the chip itself doesn't mean that those functions aren't still present on the resulting board.

Comment: I guess that the Industruino is the closest you can get to an Arduino in an Industry Standard format; https://industruino.com/. The Arduino core and libraries is the real "standard". This is where the true value is.

Answer (score 1):

- Whether or not the Arduino company goes out of business isn't all that relevant. For one thing, there are now two competing companies vying for the Arduino trademark - [arduino.cc](https://www.arduino.cc/) and [arduino.org](http://www.arduino.org/).
- The Arduino has such a ground-swell of popularity that clone boards are widely available on eBay and from other suppliers. While people are willing to buy them, someone will sell them.
- The design is open-source, which makes it a safer choice than other designs who keep their design proprietary. For one thing, it guarantees that someone will make compatible boards, even if Arduino(s) fold.
- The "heart" of the Arduino is (in most cases anyway) a chip from Atmel - so you really should ask if [Atmel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel) will go out of business. Probably not, but in any case, an alternative supplier might just as easily go out of business.
- I wouldn't be building an "Arduino board" into a production system anyway - too much chance that wires would fall out of the prototyping sockets. However the prototyping board is good for learning about their capabilities, and testing your code.

> Do Arduinos, or any other single-board computer, come in any sort of industry-standard form factor?

I'm not aware of any industry-standard form factor. The Uno design has caused a *lot* of people to make "shields" that fit onto that form factor, so that is probably the closest you would get to an industry standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a real computer, there are nowadays various options based on the Intel NUC concept.
[The Gigabyte variant](http://www.gigabyte.us/products/list.aspx?s=47&ck=104), for example. It also has GPIOS accessible through a normal pinheader, in case you need them.
And, being x86, there is virtualyl no risk of loosing the supplier.

Comment: Modern x86 processors are not always perfectly deterministic even if you write to the bare metal, which is a trait desired in many embedded systems.

Comment: And where does that requirement come from, exactly?
For sure, not from the question asked.
Btw, the x86 processor _is_ deterministic.
If you think you can write to the bare metal of an x86 machine you are fooling yourself, there is anyway a layer of microcode.
The amount of other SW running on top of it it might not be accurate, but that's a separate story. And, anyway, it was not a requirement.

Comment: No one was claiming that it was a requirement for this specific asker, nonetheless it is still worth considering before choosing a solution.